# Last three posts not being put in order by date. How to fix this?

Tags: posts, order, list, date

My company adds a quote of the day each day. The last three posts that I have put are not in order though. The first quote I posted 3 days ago is at the top the post I posted yesterday is under that, and the post from today is third down. The posts under that were all from before I posted. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Milo, go in to the edit screen for each of the posts and make sure that you haven't manually entered/edited the 'Published On' date/time.